# Detect touch and draw rectangular box on bitmap image using react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image-picker, react-native-image

I've been looking for references for some time on how to draw rectangles in an image using react native, but I can not find anything.

What I try to do is something like the user touch on the screen to mark the start position, and move, and release on the end position. We have to keep displaying the updated square.

[Example video](https://youtu.be/yjnFDDJH5rk)

[Code is available](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/09/detect-touch-and-draw-rect-on-bitmap.html) for native development using java. But I need it on react native.

Comment: please check this article. https://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/

Comment: I will check this now